# Retrofit + Jsoup : получить капчу.

Tags: android, jsoup, retrofit2, picasso

Как получить капчу с такого вида урл `http://www.name.com/captcha-image.php?ts=15294037035600` ?
Распарсить   удалось,а "скормить" imageview не получается.

- через setImageURI :`bad uri`.
- через picasso : просто не отображает.

  За основу брал [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45461260/8099156)

Comment: Попробуйте Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide Но возможно у вас что-то с парсером, может приходит поток не содержащий bitmap. Открывая вашу ссылку http://www.name.com/captcha-image.php?ts=15294037035600 я не вижу капчу

Comment: Спасибо,за совет но я кажись понял,дело в  куках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо куки нужно было добавить [referer](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) Как ,пример,этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833699/how-to-add-a-header-to-an-okhttp-request-object-that-has-been-built)

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                    .addHeader("Referer","value")
                                    .build();
                            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                        }
                    })
                    .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
                    .build();
```

Для работы с JavaNetCookieJar

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0'
```